How can I convert from .asm to .obj to .exe?
I am trying to write a simple Hello World Program using assembly and NASM. This is the code:
section .data
    hello db 'Hello, World!', 0  ; The string to print

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; Write the message to stdout
    mov rax, 1          ; syscall: write
    mov rdi, 1          ; file descriptor: stdout
    mov rsi, hello      ; address of string to output
    mov rdx, 13         ; number of bytes to write
    syscall             ; make the syscall

    ; Exit the program
    mov rax, 60         ; syscall: exit
    xor rdi, rdi        ; exit code: 0
    syscall             ; make the syscall

I can convert the .asm file to .obj using NASM. I was then instructed that in order to make the .obj an executable file I need to use the gcc compiler. I tried using that and I get the following error:
C:\Projects\OS development\OS>gcc hello.obj -o hello.exe
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crtexewin.o): in function `main':
C:/M/B/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexewin.c:67:(.text.startup+0xbd): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The complete console commands that go up to this point are:
C:\Projects\OS development\OS>nasm -f win64 hello.asm -o hello.obj

C:\Projects\OS development\OS>gcc hello.obj -o hello.exe
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crtexewin.o): in function `main':
C:/M/B/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexewin.c:67:(.text.startup+0xbd): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

As I understand it, the .obj is created normally but something is wrong with the way I have set up the gcc compiler and is unable to make the exe.
I tried using g++ and gdb instead of gcc in the command line and gdb didn't understand the "-o"
and g++ printed the same error

You forgot to show your code. You probably missed section .text or global main.

I Tried this command
gcc -e _start -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs hello.obj -o hello.exe

and it worked! Don't know why but it did

The standard entry point when using the C library is main. Your command specifies alternate entry point _start while also disabling libraries. Nevertheless that is code for linux and while your command will produce an .exe I don't think it will work. You should either use ELF gcc with WSL or a "hello world" for windows.
